# Firefox @font_face only works when it's in the root

Tags: html, firefox, css, font-face

I have this website with custom font and i m using @font_face code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'webfontregular';
    src: url('fonts/cracked-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/cracked-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/cracked-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/cracked-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/cracked-webfont.svg#webfontregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

When website is online font is not working on Firefox

**What I have tried so far :**

1-I have tried to use relative and absolute URL for font i.e `url('../../../fonts/cracked-webfont.eot');`
and `url('http://example.comfonts/cracked-webfont.eot');`

2- Tried to place CSS file that hold font code only in the root and it worked

Why font code only works in the while CSS is placed in the root even when i m using relative URL as Firefox dosen't support cross-domain font web reference

Comment: I haven't had the issue you are describing however when I have had am issue I usually get something come up in the error console in Firefox. Is this the case for you?

Comment: How about `../fonts/cracked-webfont.x` ?

Comment: @ak85 nothing in console

Comment: @Vucko Same problem :S

Comment: @AhmedSamy do you have a live link ?

Comment: http://www.cairodrive.com/beta/home

Comment: Have you checked if it works in Chrome and IE etc? Or is this ONLY a Firefox issue. Also if it works when you put it in the root, then you know there is no issue with the font itself, so it definitely sounds like you might be incorrectly referencing the location of the font.

Comment: Well only Firefox, but it seems to be working now for no reason

Comment: Sounds like it was probably just a cache issue then.

Answer (score 0):

In firebug check to see if the all resources have been loaded under the 'net' tab, if they have then maybe there is a problem with that font.